# Is there a way to read password protected PDFs with tabula-py?

Tags: pdf, password-protection, tabula-py

I have password protected PDFs with some tables. (I have the passwords to them).

Currently I'm using PDFminer.six to extract data from these PDFs to text but I want to use tabula-py instead to extract tables.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After spending an extra few minutes on the documentation, I realised that read_pdf accepts a "password" argument....